# Webpage quickest redirection To Mobile

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, nginx, squid

I would like to redirect any request for my web page to my mobile page (based on the screen size)

1. We have all layers like `Ngnix`, `SQUID`, `Spring` application.

   I'm trying to do it in the web page (the `JSP`), in the `javascript` block. But my `JSP` page where i had my redirect is very huge (I cant fix it now). Its working but, it loads the complete page and then does the redirect, which isnt the optimal thing. Where else can i handle this (`Ngnix/SQUID`)?
2. If I'm forced to do it in `JS/web` page, is there anyway I can do that in without loading the huge page?

Thanks
Mahesh

Answer (score 0):

Check this article out on css-tricks.com by Chris Coyier. In the article he discusses how to mobile redirect visitors based on screen size or targeting specific mobile options.

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/redirect-mobile-devices/

Comment: If you post a link, at least summarize what it says for future visitors.

Comment: Also I would add on your body onload which will let you choose when to redirect after dom loads or before. You can also use ! marks to set importance on scripts.

Comment: onload is most often used within the <body> element to execute a script once a web page has completely loaded all content (including images, script files, CSS files, etc.).

Comment: I dont want to do it loading all the stuff, like I said the page is huge